# Nagios missing alert notification

Tags: nagios

I check my server on WAN with ping and https by Nagios Core 3.5.1.
Here is the host alert history.

```
June 23, 2015 18:00     

Service Ok[06-23-2015 18:13:47] SERVICE ALERT: webserver;PING;OK;HARD;3;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 33.72 ms
Service Ok[06-23-2015 18:13:40] SERVICE ALERT: webserver;HTTPS;OK;HARD;3;HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 359 bytes in 0.201 second response time
Host Up[06-23-2015 18:06:29] HOST ALERT: webserver;UP;SOFT;8;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 33.92 ms
Host Down[06-23-2015 18:05:25] HOST ALERT: webserver;DOWN;SOFT;7;CRITICAL - Time to live exceeded (1.2.)
Host Down[06-23-2015 18:04:19] HOST ALERT: webserver;DOWN;SOFT;6;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%
Service Critical[06-23-2015 18:03:53] SERVICE ALERT: webserver;PING;CRITICAL;HARD;3;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%
Host Down[06-23-2015 18:03:49] HOST ALERT: webserver;DOWN;SOFT;5;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%
Service Critical[06-23-2015 18:03:49] SERVICE ALERT: webserver;HTTPS;CRITICAL;HARD;3;CRITICAL - Socket timeout after 10 seconds
Host Down[06-23-2015 18:02:19] HOST ALERT: webserver;DOWN;SOFT;4;(Host check timed out after 30.01 seconds)
Service Critical[06-23-2015 18:01:53] SERVICE ALERT: webserver;PING;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%
Service Critical[06-23-2015 18:01:49] SERVICE ALERT: webserver;HTTPS;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;CRITICAL - Socket timeout after 10 seconds
Host Down[06-23-2015 18:01:48] HOST ALERT: webserver;DOWN;SOFT;3;(Host check timed out after 30.01 seconds)
Host Down[06-23-2015 18:00:18] HOST ALERT: webserver;DOWN;SOFT;2;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%

June 23, 2015 17:00     

Service Critical[06-23-2015 17:59:53] SERVICE ALERT: webserver;PING;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 100%
Service Critical[06-23-2015 17:59:49] SERVICE ALERT: webserver;HTTPS;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;CRITICAL - Socket timeout after 10 seconds
Host Down[06-23-2015 17:58:48] HOST ALERT: webserver;DOWN;SOFT;1;(Host check timed out after 30.02 seconds)
Service Ok[06-23-2015 17:29:48] SERVICE ALERT: webserver;PING;OK;SOFT;2;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 34.72 ms
```

So, 17:29 o'clock was everthing all right.
17:58 o'clock till 18:05 o'clock was Packet loss = 100% and Socket timeout.

My Question is, why didn't I get a notification?

Some days bevor and today I get "warning" notifications just fine, but I never get a "critical" notification.

Here is my contact.cfg

```
define contact{
    contact_name                    nagiosadmin             ; Short name of user
    use                             generic-contact         ; Inherit default values from generic-contact template (defined above)
    alias                           Nagios Admin            ; Full name of user
    email                           user@localhost     ; <<***** CHANGE THIS TO YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS ******
    }
```

Here is my templates.cfg

```
define contact{
    name                            generic-contact         ; The name of this contact template
    service_notification_period     24x7                    ; service notifications can be sent anytime
    host_notification_period        24x7                    ; host notifications can be sent anytime
    service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f,s             ; send notifications for all service states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
    host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s               ; send notifications for all host states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
    service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email ; send service notifications via email
    host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email    ; send host notifications via email
    register                        0                       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL CONTACT, JUST A TEMPLATE!
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That you did not receive notifications is because all the reported states are `SOFT`. Notifications are only sent out for `HARD` states.

You need to look into the service configuration and check the value of `max_check_attempts` for your service.

Comment: there are 2 `HARD` states `PING;CRITICAL;HARD;3;` and `HTTPS;CRITICAL;HARD;3;` at 18:03 o'clock. What about them?

Comment: Sorry, I first thought it was about the Host down states and overlooked the Service ones. Can you confirm that nagios did not sent the notification or that it might be a mailer issue? Look at the 'View notifications for this host` for the specific day and see if it indeed does not show a notification for the Ping service event. You might have a mailer issue so please verify your mail log also.

Comment: Nagios didn't send a notification, not in `View Notifications For This Host` nor in `var/nagios.log`. But your hint with `max_check_attempts` is good. For Service it is obviously `3` but for host it is `10`. So I guess it will not send notification about services because of host is unreachable, so Nagios will wait until host is also in `HARD` state